# Validating a Cell input before the bound object is updated

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have objects bound to a DataGridView using a BindingList.

I need to validate the data keyed into a cell before the underlying bound object property gets updated.

I am trying to use `CellValidating` event, but I have set up breakpoints and the property of the bound object gets the new value before `CellValidating` does.

I am looking for an event similar to `CellBeforeUpdate` which does not exist in this Grid.

Am I missing something obvious?

{Edit, this was a programming error. I inserted a column which shifted indexes by 1 and the code in the CellValidating event was looking at the incorrect comment.

I think a better practice is to use the column name as opposed to index to avoid a mistake such as this one}

Comment: Can you post your code, please?  Or what you have tried and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The usual sequence is `CellValidating`, `CellValueChanged`, `CellValidated`, `CellEndEdit`. In `CellValidating`, the underlying data object is unchanged.

Comment: There is not much code to paste that would be of any help. I have a BindingList bound to a datagridview. I have a cell column ItemCode which is bound to the ItemCode property of the objects in the Bindinglist. I put a breakpoint in the property setter and when I edit the cell, it hits the setter breakpoint BEFORE the CellValidating event fires.

Comment: I apologize for wasting everyone's time. It was a programming error. I was accessing the column using the index instead of column name, and I had added a column in front which shifted all the indexes by one. The Cellvalidating event was firing *after* the setting because it was for a different column which was updating the data based on the value entered in the column in question. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with your comment that…

> *”the property of the bound object gets the new value before
> CellValidating does.”* …

The underlying data source does not change until execution “leaves” the grids `CellValidating` event.

Put a break point at the beginning of the `CellValidating` event. Then run the code, make a change to a cell in the grid and then try to leave the cell. When the break point hits, take a look at the underlying data source. It will NOT show the change that is in the grids cell.

Since you show no code, I can only assume that in the `CellValidating` event, there is “some” kind of check to validate that the data in the cell is invalid. How you check this is unknown and we can only assume you are checking the right value.

In any case however, if you check the value in the cell and determine it is an invalid value and want to set the cells value to its original value “before” the edit, then a call to the grids `CancelEdit()` method should do this for you. Something like…

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.FormattedValue.ToString() == "some invalid value") {
    dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
  }
}
```

***Edit…***

To help, the best I can do is demonstrate that what you say is happening... is NOT reproducible with the given info.

From what I can decipher…

1. The grid uses a `BindingList<T>` as a `DataSource` to the grid.
2. It is unknow what “T” is and we can only guess it is a basic class.
3. The grid has subscribed (wired up) to its `CellValidating` event.

Now if we try and reproduce this… a “basic” Class may look something like below, where one `int` property of this class is named “ItemCode” as per your comment. Also, an additional `string` property is added named “ItemName.” About as basic as you can get…

```
public class ItemClass {
  public int ItemCode { get; set; }
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

To help, we will create a `GetData` method that returns a `BindingList<ItemClass>` of 15 `ItemClass` objects. We will use this binding list as a data source to the grid.

```
private BindingList<ItemClass> GetData() {
  BindingList<ItemClass> bl = new BindingList<ItemClass>();
  for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    bl.Add(new ItemClass { ItemCode = i, ItemName = "Item " + i });
  }
  return bl;
}
```

Next, we need to wire up the grids `CellValidating` event. In this example, since the `ItemCode` is an `int` value, the `CellValidating` event would be a good place to check and make sure the user typed a valid `int` value into the cell. Otherwise, there is a chance the user could type characters and throw the grids `DataError.` In this example, if the text is not a valid `int` value, then the cell’s value is returned to its original value before the edit.

This give us a good reason the wire up this event, but it is also convenient so we can check to see what value is in the `BindingList<ItemClass>` list when the user “changes” a cells value.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
    if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out int value)) {
      dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
    }
  }
}
```

So, create a new winforms project and drop a `DataGridView` onto the form. Other than the code above, the only code we need is below…

```
BindingList<ItemClass> GridBindingList;

public Form2() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridBindingList = GetData();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridBindingList;
}
```

We create a “global” variable `GridBindingList` so we can check its values at any breakpoint we set. In the forms `Load` event, the `GridBindingList` is filled with test data and finally the grids `DataSource` is set to this binding list.

This is the closest I can decipher as to matching your code since you refuse to show it.

You state that when the user types text into a cell in the grid and then tries to leave that cell… that the `GridBindingList` gets updated with the text in the grid's cell “BEFORE” the grids `CellValidating` event is called.

And I stand by my comment that you are mistaken about this. Using the code above, you should be able to test this yourself.

When executed, the code above should produce something like the form on the left…

After editing the second item in the grid it may look something like the form on the right…

[image]

Then leave the cell, the grids `CellValidating` event fires. The break point is met and execution stops on the first line in the event as shown below.

As shown, the `GridBindingList`’s second item has NOT changed yet as you state. In addition, lower in the watch list, we can see the formatted value “fsdgfdgdf” is still displayed in the grid.

[image]

Can you provide the code that reproduces what you describe? From your comment to this answer…

> *”I put breakpoints in the property of the underlying object and it 100% fires before the CellValidating event.”* …

Then “SHOW” an example of this. I hope this example demonstrates that the underlying data source does NOT change before the grids `CellValidating` event fires.

Comment: @Kim… Then show your code that can re-produce this. My test using a `DataTable` as a data source does not do as you describe. Without some code to reproduce your problem, all we have is your word. And from my test what you state is not correct. Please show an example of what you describe so that we can copy and paste to re-produce the problem. Without an example, it is a guess as to “why” we are getting different results.

Comment: I apologize for wasting everyone's time. It was a programming error. I was accessing the column using the index instead of column name, and I had added a column in front which shifted all the indexes by one. The Cellvalidating event was firing *after* the setter because it was for a different column which was updating the data based on the value entered in the column in question. My bad.